# Optimizations are killing my integer overflow checks in clang 6

Tags: c++, c++11, optimization, integer-overflow, fixed-point

I have a fixed-point implementation for some financial application. It's basically an integer wrapped in a class that is based on the number of decimals given `N`treated as a decimal number. The class is paranoid and checks for overflows, but when I ran my tests in release mode, and they failed, and finally I created this minimal example that demonstrates the problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

template <typename T, typename U>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<U, std::string>::value, T>::type 
FromString(U&& str)
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << str;
    T ret;
    ss >> ret;
    return ret;
}

int main()
{
    int NewAccu=32;
    int N=10;

    using T = int64_t;

    T l = 10;
    T r = FromString<T>("1" + std::string(NewAccu - N, '0'));
    if (l == 0 || r == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    T res = l * r;
    std::cout << l << std::endl;
    std::cout << r << std::endl;
    std::cout << res << std::endl;
    std::cout << (res / l) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;
    if ((res / l) != r) {
        throw std::runtime_error(
                   "FixedPoint Multiplication Overflow while upscaling [:" + std::to_string(l) + ", " + std::to_string(r) + "]");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This happens with Clang 6, my version is:

```
$ clang++ --version
clang version 6.0.0-1ubuntu2 (tags/RELEASE_600/final)
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
```

It's funny because it's an impressive optimization, but this ruins my application and prevents me from detecting overflows. I was able to reproduce this problem [in g++ here](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e47c98b47e2e3c25). It doesn't throw an exception there.

Notice that the exception is thrown in debug mode, but it's not in release mode.

Comment: What about using `volatile`?

Comment: @curiousguy That may be a possible solution. I'll try it now. But isn't that an overkill? It'll destroy all optimizations in my program!

Comment: `volatile` applies strictly to one variable, it doesn't inhibit the optimisations before or after. It does break value propagation through the volatile variable, though. Like outputting to a local socket and reading back the same value (such that the compiler wouldn't possibly know is the same). So it depends on whether you want value propagation or a simple fix.

Comment: Also see [Detecting signed overflow in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32317442/1708801)

Comment: For overflow-trapping fixed-point arithmetic, consider [CNL](https://github.com/johnmcfarlane/cnl).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As *@Basile* already stated, signed integer overflow is an *undefined behavior*, so the compiler can handle it in any way - even optimizing it away to gain a performance advantage. So **detecting** integer overflow after its occurence is way too late. Instead, you should **predict** integer overflow just before it occurs.

Here is my implementation of overflow prediction of integer multiplication:

```
#include <limits>

template <typename T>
bool predict_mul_overflow(T x, T y)
{
    static_assert(std::numeric_limits<T>::is_integer, "predict_mul_overflow expects integral types");

    if constexpr (std::numeric_limits<T>::is_bounded)
    {
        return ((x != T{0}) && ((std::numeric_limits<T>::max() / x) < y));
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The function returns `true` if the integer multiplication `x * y` is predicted to overflow.

Note that while `unsigned` overflow is well-defined in terms of [modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic), `signed` overflow is an [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Nevertheless, the presented function works for `signed` and `unsigned` `T` types as well.

Comment: Is an overflow checker returning optional<T> faster if it's likely to not overflow?

Comment: @sandthorn Do you mean returning the optional result of the arithmetic operation, when overflow doesn't occur?

Comment: Exactly. But I'm not sure optional<T> requires allocation? if yes, that might slower things down.

Comment: @sandthorn Since the prediction doesn't use the arithmetic result, you can compute the result before the prediction, and throwing it away when you predict an overflow.

Comment: I allowed myself to make a little change that works with `boost::multiprecision`. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @plasmacel shouldn't that "else" be `true` based on your convention? No overflow is `true`, right?

Comment: Also see [Detecting signed overflow in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32317442/1708801)

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist No, it predicts overflow, so it returns `true` when overflow will happen.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to detect (signed) [integer overflows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow) (on scalar types like `int64_t` or `long`), you should use appropriate builtins, often compiler specific.

For GCC, see [integer overflow builtins](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Integer-Overflow-Builtins.html).

Integer overflow (on plain `int` or `long` or other signed integral type) is an instance of [**undefined behavior**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), so the compiler can optimize as it please against it. Be [scared](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25636788/841108). If you depend on UB you are no more coding in standard C++ and your program is tied to a particular compiler and system, so is not [portable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_portability) at all (even to other compilers, other compiler versions, other compilation flags, other computers and OSes). So Clang (or GCC) is allowed to optimize against integer overflow, and sometimes does.

Or consider using some [bignum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic) package (then of course you don't deal with just predefined C++ integral scalar types). Perhaps [GMPlib](http://gmplib.org/).

You could consider using GCC's [`__int128`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fint128.html) if your numbers fit into 128 bits.

I believe you cannot reliably detect integer overflows when they happen (unless you use the [integer overflow builtins](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Integer-Overflow-Builtins.html)). You should avoid them (or use some bignum library, or some library using these builtins, etc.).

Comment: I was gonna respond to your comment. This is not always valid for me because I'm using `boost::multiprecision`. The class is a template class.

Comment: It is still possible to do reliable overflow predicates, predicting, instead of catching the overflow. As you already said, when overflow occurs, that is undefined behavior, and compilers can do whatever they want.

Comment: @plasmacel I was trying to detect overflows in my program... doesn't seem to work!

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist As I see you are trying to detect overflow **after** it happened. You should predict it before it happens.

Comment: @plasmacel I'll research that a little bit and try. If you have a solution, please post it.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist: Why don't you use [integer overflow builtins](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Integer-Overflow-Builtins.html)? They answer your needs!

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Because I'm using a template class that mostly takes `boost::multiprecision` and I need a precision of up to 512 bits. This int64_t is a special case. It would be very painful to specialize things manually.

Comment: Integer overflow gives undefined behaviour on any *signed* integral type (other than class types that emulate behaviour of integral types).   It is not undefined for unsigned types.    In any event, the undefined behaviour means it is impossible *in standard C++* to detect overflow after the fact.   It is necessary to check if an operation would overflow, and throw the exception BEFORE actually doing the operation.

Comment: Does `boost::multiprecision` define its signed integer overflow behavior? Signed integer overflow is undefined behavior by the standard, so you are on boost::multiprecision's hands now.

Comment: @sandthorn That's one more thing to research. I think they have a "checked" type, but I was hoping I wouldn't need to distinguish between types. I think predicting overflows is the safest solution.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Btw, thank you for the help. Appreciate it!