# Overflow errors without climits library

Tags: c++

I was working on a programming problem, is there a way to check for overflow errors for a signed 32-bit integer without the use INT_MIN and INT_MAX macros of climits.

Comment: What type of operation you are performing with the integer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detecting signed overflow in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3944505/detecting-signed-overflow-in-c-c)

Answer (score 2):

It's impossible to check for overflow errors using *any* technique. That's because the behaviour of signed `int` overflow is *undefined* in C++.

What you *can* do is write pre-emptive code that detects a potential overflow. The nature of that code is contingent on the operations you are performing. But it would be rather difficult to do that without using `std::numeric_limits<int>` functionality (which supersedes `INT_MIN` and `INT_MAX`) if you want to write portable C++.