# Can I check built-in type at runtime?

Tags: c++, c++17, typechecking

For example,

If I write:

```
char c = CHAR_MAX;
c++;
```

Can I know if 'c++' results in `int` or `char` so I know for sure if its not an overflow?

Comment: `c++` results in `char`. Why do you want to check it at runtime?

Comment: I believe `char` is converted to `int` before that.

Comment: @user963241 _"I believe char is converted to int before that."_ No, that's not the case.

Comment: @user963241 `c + 1` is `int`, but `c++` is `char` :-) Also, `char` can be weird when doing arithmetic. See: https://blog.knatten.org/2019/05/24/no-one-knows-the-type-of-char-char/

Comment: You should be able to know for sure that it is an overflow.

Comment: Even if the result of 'c++' is a float, c itself is a char. There is no chance in c++ at all that a type will change. As a type of anything can't change in c++, it can not change in compile and or runtime. As this, it makes no sense to check it! If you write : `auto x = c++` you can check for the result type which is the type of x. For this you can use 'std::is_same' or other stuff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I know if 'c++' results in `int` or `char`

As per standard quote in [L.F.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56313069/2079303), you can know that it results in `char`.

> so I know for sure if its not an overflow?

You can know for sure that it is an overflow. On systems where `char` is a signed type, the behaviour of the program will be undefined as far as I can tell.

> Can I check built-in type at runtime?

You cannot check built-in types at *runtime*, but you can check them already at *compiletime*. For example:

```
static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(c++), char>);
```

> when I say: `signed char c = CHAR_MAX + 1 then CHAR_MAX + 1` becomes `int` result and then in is assigned to `c` which is implementation-defined.

Indeed. Except on exotic systems where `sizeof(signed char) == sizeof(int)` in which case there is no promotion, and the arithmetic causes overflow which is undefined behaviour.

And only until C++20. Since C++20, signed initialisation with unrepresentable value is defined by the standard.

> Can I ever make signed char overflow?

Yes. Using the increment operator. As far as I can tell, the standard says nothing about promotion within the increment operator. However, this may be open to interpretation.

Comment: Can I ever make `signed char` overflow? E.g. when I say: `signed char c = CHAR_MAX + 1` then  `CHAR_MAX + 1` becomes `int` result and then this `int` result is assigned to `c` which is implementation-defined and gets converted.

Comment: @user963241 that's described in standard. increment is an IB if value cannot fit.

Comment: In my example was it an overflow, yes? Because I suppose increment operator `++` is different from `c = c + 1`? When you said `You can know for sure that it is an overflow` it means 'yes, it is overflow'?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what you mean by "check at runtime", but I can tell you for sure that `c++` results in a prvalue of type `char`, and `c` is always `char`. `c` is never converted to `int`.

Per [[expr.post.incr]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.post.incr#1):

> The value of a postfix `++` expression is the value of its operand.
>   [ *Note:* The value obtained is a copy of the original value
>   — *end note* ] The operand shall be a modifiable lvalue. The
>   type of the operand shall be an arithmetic type other than *cv*
>   `bool`, or a pointer to a complete object type. **The value of the
>   operand object is modified by adding `1` to it.** The value computation
>   of the `++` expression is sequenced before the modification of the
>   operand object. With respect to an indeterminately-sequenced function
>   call, the operation of postfix `++` is a single evaluation. [ *Note:*
>   Therefore, a function call shall not intervene between the
>   lvalue-to-rvalue conversion and the side effect associated with any
>   single postfix `++` operator. — *end note* ] The result is a
>   prvalue. **The type of the result is the cv-unqualified version of the
>   type of the operand**. If the operand is a bit-field that cannot
>   represent the incremented value, the resulting value of the bit-field
>   is implementation-defined. See also [expr.add] and [expr.ass].

As mentioned by [Nikos C.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/856199) in comment, you should check if `c == CHAR_MAX` prior to incrementing. For more about checking for signed overflow, see [Detecting signed overflow in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3944505).

Comment: And if the OP wants to guard against overflow, then they need to check if `c == CHAR_MAX` prior to incrementing it.

Comment: @NikosC. Thanks. I have incorporated that into my answer.

Comment: Thanks, what I meant was that when I do `c++`, it means `c = c + 1` and here before doing `c + 1` the `c` becomes `int` and then `int` is assigned to `c`.

Comment: @L.F.: Does it mean no such promotions occur to get the final result in `char`?

Comment: @user963241 That’s right. No promotion is involved.

Comment: @L.F.: In case of pre-increment `++x` it appears pretty clearly defined.

Comment: @user963241 How? Isn't `x++` equally clearly defined?

Comment: @L.F.: It says "The expression ++x is equivalent to x+=1" so promotions do occur in this case.