# Are there overflow check math functions for MSVC?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, integer-overflow

While looking for functions that do overflow checks on signed and unsigned integer arithmetics, I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32317442/2905768), which presents nice compiler intrinsics to do checked math in GCC. Since the code I'm currently writing needs to be cross-platform, I need something similar for the MSVC (Microsoft Visual Studio) compiler as well.

Does that exist or do I have to implement it manually?

Comment: [Boost Safe Numerics](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/libs/safe_numerics/doc/html/index.html)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Boost is not being used in this project so far, but I'll consider this option.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/intsafe/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For unsigned addition and subtraction, MSVC has `_addcarry_u16/32/64` and `_subborrow_u16/32/64`, all defined in [<intrin.h>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/x64-amd64-intrinsics-list?view=msvc-160). They seem to produce optimal code, including generating `add` and `sub` instead of `adc` and `sbb` if you pass constant 0 for the carry in.

Unfortunately, there are no analogous intrinsics that return the overflow flag.

For 64×64 multiplication, [`__mulh`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/mulh?view=msvc-160) and [`__umulh`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/umulh?view=msvc-160) return the high 64 bits of the result, which you can compare with 0 in the unsigned case or `low >> 63` in the signed case. There are also `_[u]mul128` functions that return the whole result, but I think they would be more cumbersome to use and would generate the same code with optimization on (I haven't tested that).

For division, there are [`_[u]div64`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/div64?view=msvc-160) and [`_[u]div128`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/div128?view=msvc-160), defined in `<immintrin.h>`. It seems to be undocumented what they do in the case of overflow, but they most likely raise #DE, which could be caught with SEH.

In other cases, there's probably nothing better than to calculate the result at a higher precision and then bounds-check it.

Comment: Looks like that's pretty much it. `_addcarry_u32` returns the carry flag, which is exactly what is required. I'll test these today.

Comment: `intsafe.h`, mentioned by Hans above seems to be a bit more complete, but both are doing the job, thanks.