# Signed integer overflow

Tags: c, integer-overflow

Below in source code (I've commented the error on code), I get

> Line 27: Char 33: runtime error: signed integer overflow: -1094795586+ -1094795586 cannot be represented in type 'int'

I've consulted different articles, like [How to detected signed integer overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3944505/detecting-signed-overflow-in-c-c) but I'm not getting which integer to check.
Elements of `working_array[]` are filtered from `nums[]` if their value is less than `target` integer.
Since the elements of `nums[]` are like `[ 3, 6, 11, 19, 2, ...]` I'm not worried to checking for overflow during SUM on the last `if` statement. I'm wrong?

```
int* twoSum(int* nums, int numsSize, int target, int* returnSize){
    int count_elem = 0;
    int *working_array = (int*)malloc(numsSize * sizeof(int));
    
    // Going through original array
    for(int i=0;i<numsSize;i++){
        
        // If elem nums[i] is less than target, is accepted on a new working array
        if(nums[i] < target){
            count_elem += 1;
            working_array[count_elem] = nums[i];            
        }        
    }

    working_array = realloc(working_array, count_elem*sizeof(int));
    
    // Creating result array
    returnSize = sizeof(int)*2;
    int *result_array = (int*)malloc(returnSize);

    // Going through working array
    for(int i=0;i<count_elem;++i)
        for(int j=0;j<count_elem;++j)

            // SIGNED INTEGER OVERFLOW IN LINE BELOW
            if( (working_array[i]+working_array[j]) == target){
                result_array[0] = working_array[i];
                result_array[1] = working_array[j];
                free(working_array);
                return result_array;
            }
    
    free(working_array);
    return;
}
```

P.S: I know that [cast malloc results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) is useless, but this is a minor issue maybe.

Comment: Please create a [mcve].

Comment: `returnSize = sizeof(int)*2;` : But `returnSize` is a pointer?  You should get a big red warning on this.

Comment: Yes I was missing that. By using `sizeof(int)*2`  in place of `returnSize` pointer, the issue persists the same...

Comment: A lot of people don't believe that signed integer overflow is possible, or ask how to detect it.  Yet it looks like your platform detected and rather nicely diagnosed it without your even asking!  What platform is this?

Comment: @SteveSummit the error on this post, is related to LeetCode website's debugger. I was solving an exercise. (note that my question was about a compiling error, and not about how to solve the exercise itself)

Comment: @bersi Fascinating.  Thanks.  That's a point in LeetCode's favor, then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        if(nums[i] < target){
            count_elem += 1;
            working_array[count_elem] = nums[i];     
        }
```

Off-by-one error.  This initializes `working_array[1]`, `working_array[2]`, ... potentially up to `working_array[numsSize]` which would be out of bounds.  Meanwhile, `working_array[0]` is never initialized and contains garbage, which is probably the garbage value that provokes your overflow.

Make it:

```
        if(nums[i] < target){
            working_array[count_elem] = nums[i];     
            count_elem += 1;
        }
```

or perhaps

```
        if(nums[i] < target){
            working_array[count_elem++] = nums[i];     
        }
```

---

Also, as noted above,

```
    returnSize = sizeof(int)*2;
    int *result_array = (int*)malloc(returnSize);
```

is wrong because `returnSize` is a pointer.  If the idea is to return the size by reference, then you want

```
    *returnSize = sizeof(int)*2;
    int *result_array = (int*)malloc(*returnSize);
```

Comment: Thank you for clarification. The first element of working_array, as initialized, solved the issue. Sorry again for missing the pointer used in the malloc...