# Safely check if signed multiplication would overflow in C++17

Tags: c++, c++17, undefined-behavior, integer-arithmetic

I'm looking for a convenient idiom to check if a multiplication of two signed integers (`long`s or `long long`s) would overflow in versions of C++ where signed arithmetic overflow is undefined behavior (C or C++17 and earlier).  I'm okay using any library functions available in C++17, but in an ideal world would like something cheaper than integer division (e.g., checking `b <= std::numeric_limits<long long>::max() / a` or `b >= std::numeric_limits<long long>::lowest() / a` or permutations with `-b` depending on the signedness of the arguments). In an ideal world the solution would be something the compiler could optimize away (so also not manually performing the multiplication one word at a time).

I'd like to avoid any idioms that first perform the multiplication, then sanity-check the result, because a compiler might remove the sanity check based on the assumption that signed arithmetic cannot overflow.  (After all, overflow would be undefined behavior, so the compiler can assume the programmer would never let that happen.)  Unfortunately, most algorithms I've seen suggested are of this form, so would appear to be unsafe.

Comment: Do not tag C for C++ questions.

Comment: I would be happy for a solution in C, too.

Comment: If using g++: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-13.2.0/gcc/Integer-Overflow-Builtins.html (I believe this works with clang++ too)

Comment: If you want a C answer, you can ask separately. Policy is not to tag both C and C++ except when asking about differences or interactions between the two languages. Combining tags introduces problems, such as a person seeking C solutions finding questions tagged C only to be disappointed that the predominant answers are C++. You can ask separate questions and include links between them so that people interested in both can find both.

Comment: I guess I want the problem solved in C.  If there's some magic in the C++17 library, I would settle for that.  But I think the most likely solution is in C.

Comment: I think you have a misconception about C++20. Signed arithmetic overflow is still undefined behavior. What changed is that conversions from unsigned to signed, which used to be implementation-defined (not undefined!) now have a specified behavior.

Comment: All the answers in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3944505/detecting-signed-overflow-in-c-c address *addition*, not multiplication, but there's probably useful information to be gleaned anyways.

Comment: @ruakh Thanks.  I guess it's worse than I expected.

Comment: Ooo, C23 has a `<stdckdint.h>` header with macros for overflow detection, but that's not really feasible to use since AFAIK no compilers support it yet.

Comment: Are you OK with using GCC built-in functions? https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Integer-Overflow-Builtins.html

Comment: Some discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1815367/catch-and-compute-overflow-during-multiplication-of-two-large-integers).

Comment: Easiest way to see if multiplication of two `int32_t` would overflow, do the multiplication in `int64_t`, and if the result is in range of min/max `int32_t` it did not overflow.

Comment: Actually you can multiply and then do a sanity check, if you convert to an unsigned type first. The bits of the result are not going to change.

Answer (score 4):

For clang and gcc, just use their [builtins](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Integer-Overflow-Builtins.html#index-_005f_005fbuiltin_005fmul_005foverflow)

```cpp
#include<optional>

template<typename I>
std::optional<I> mul(I x, I y) {
    I res;
    if(__builtin_mul_overflow(x, y, &res))
        return {};
    return res;
}
```

For msvc, perform multiplication in wider integers when possible, and use [__mulh](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/mulh?view=msvc-160) otherwise

```cpp
#include<intrin.h>
#include<cstdint>
#include<optional>
#include<limits>

template<typename I>
std::optional<I> mul(I x, I y)
{
    if constexpr(std::is_same_v<I, std::int64_t>)
    {
        auto hi = __mulh(x, y);
        auto lo = std::uint64_t(x) * std::uint64_t(y);
        auto neg = lo >> 63;

        if(hi != 0 && hi != -1)
            return {};
        if((hi == 0 && neg) || (hi == -1 && !neg))
            return {};
        return x * y;
    }
    else
    {
        auto res = std::int64_t(x) * y;
        if(res > std::numeric_limits<I>::max() || res < std::numeric_limits<I>::min())
            return {};
        return I(res);
    }
}
```

While test division is often taught and somewhat simpler conceptually, it is atrociously slow. Using these intrinsics are expected to be significantly faster due to hardware support and less branching. For example, [micro benchmarking](https://quick-bench.com/q/FVw-Hqqe9GaJi7dVemF_yUBg9UQ) shows a 81x speedup for clang intrinsics over test division.

Answer (score 1):

See function `multiplication_would_overflow`.

```cpp
// main.ixx
//
// RESOURCES:
// 
// Chapter 5 of "Secure Coding in C and C++" by Seacord
// https://ptgmedia.pearsoncmg.com/images/0321335724/samplechapter/seacord_ch05.pdf
//
// How do I detect unsigned integer multiply overflow?
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199333/how-do-i-detect-unsigned-integer-multiply-overflow
//
// Detecting signed overflow in C/C++
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3944505/detecting-signed-overflow-in-c-c
//
// SafeInt
// https://github.com/dcleblanc/SafeInt/blob/master/SafeInt.hpp
//
// Clang: Checked Arithmetic Builtins
// http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#checked-arithmetic-builtins

export module main;
import std;

template< typename integer_type >
constexpr bool addition_would_overflow(
    integer_type const lop, 
    integer_type const rop)
{
    enum : integer_type { zero };
    auto const max{ std::numeric_limits<integer_type>::max() };
    auto const min{ std::numeric_limits<integer_type>::min() };
    return rop < zero
        ? (lop < min - rop)
        : (lop > max - rop);
}
template< typename integer_type >
constexpr bool subtraction_would_overflow(
    integer_type const lop, 
    integer_type const rop)
{
    enum : integer_type { zero };
    auto const max{ std::numeric_limits<integer_type>::max() };
    auto const min{ std::numeric_limits<integer_type>::min() };
    return rop < zero
        ? (lop > max + rop)
        : (lop < min + rop);
}
template< typename integer_type >
constexpr bool multiplication_would_overflow(
    integer_type const lop, 
    integer_type const rop)
{
    enum : integer_type { zero };
    auto const max{ std::numeric_limits<integer_type>::max() };
    auto const min{ std::numeric_limits<integer_type>::min() };
    return lop != zero
        && rop != zero
        && (lop < zero
            ? (rop < zero ? lop < max / rop : lop < min / rop)
            : (rop < zero ? rop < min / lop : lop > max / rop)
            );
}
template< typename integer_type >
constexpr bool division_would_overflow(
    integer_type const lop, 
    integer_type const rop)
{
    enum : integer_type { zero, minus1 = -1 };
    auto const max{ std::numeric_limits<integer_type>::max() };
    auto const min{ std::numeric_limits<integer_type>::min() };
    if constexpr (std::is_signed_v<integer_type>)
    {
        if (lop == min && rop == minus1 ||
            rop == min && lop == minus1)
            return true;
    }
    return rop == zero;
}

export int main()
{
    using integer_type = long long;
    integer_type const one{ 1 }, two{ 2 }, minus1{ -1 };
    auto const max{ std::numeric_limits<integer_type>::max() };
    auto const min{ std::numeric_limits<integer_type>::min() };

    std::cout << std::boolalpha
        << "addition       : " << addition_would_overflow(max, one)
        << "\nsubtraction    : " << subtraction_would_overflow(min, one)
        << "\nmultiplication : " << multiplication_would_overflow(max, two)
        << "\ndivision       : " << division_would_overflow(min, minus1)
        << "\n\n";
    return 0;
}
// end file: main.ixx
```

Comment: Ouch.  That is the brute-force method, but looks unlikely to be optimizable by the compiler.  Crazy that you have to jump through these hoops to multiply two integers you get from an untrusted source.

Comment: Yeah. It is unfortunate that you have to do a division to check whether multiplication is safe.