# Why do the INC and DEC instructions *not* affect the Carry Flag (CF)?

Tags: assembly, x86, increment, flags, decrement

Why do the x86 instruction `INC` (increment) and `DEC` (decrement) not affect the `CF` (carry flag) in FLAGSREGISTER?

Comment: @AndreasBrinck That question is not about the “why?”, nor do the answers there answer the question of the design choice.

Comment: THIS IS NOT AN EXACT DUPLICATE. The other question asks how to *use* INC/DEC and simply observes the carry is not updated.  This questions asks *why* it is not updated.    I find the fact that several people are willing to close the question as an exact duplicate when it is not, an indication that "moderators" are jumping the gun.  That isn't helpful IMHO for SO.

Comment: Semi-related: [x86 Assembly: INC and DEC instruction and overflow flag](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3925528) shows some examples of how the update OF but not CF.  That's the non-duplicate this question was mistakenly linked to at one point.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

To understand why you probably need to remember the current "x86" CPUs with 32 and 64 bit values started life as much more limited 8-bit machines, going back to the Intel 8008.  (I coded in this world back in 1973, I still remember (ugh) it!).

In that world, registers were precious and small.   You need `INC`/`DEC` for various purposes, the most common being loop control.  Many loops involved doing "multi-precision arithmetic" (e.g, 16 bits or more!) By having `INC`/`DEC` set the Zero flag (`Z`), you could use them to control loops pretty nicely; by insisting the loop control instructions not change the Carry flag (`CF`), the carry is preserved across loop iterations and you can implement multiprecision operations without writing tons of code to remember the carry state.

This worked pretty well, once you got used to the ugly instruction set.

On more modern machines with larger word sizes, you don't need this is much, so `INC` and `DEC` could be semantically equivalent to `ADD` ...,1 etc.   That in fact is what I use when I need the carry set :-}

Mostly, I stay away from `INC` and `DEC` now, because they do partial condition code updates, and this can cause funny stalls in the pipeline, and `ADD`/`SUB` don't.  So where it doesn't matter (most places), I use `ADD`/`SUB` to avoid the stalls.  I use `INC`/`DEC` only when keeping the code small matters, e.g., fitting in a cache line where the size of one or two instructions makes enough difference to matter.  This is probably pointless nano[literally!]-optimization, but I'm pretty old-school in my coding habits.

My explanation tells us why `INC`/`DEC` set the Zero flag (`Z`).  I don't have a particularly compelling explanation for why `INC`/`DEC` set the sign (and the Parity flag).

EDIT April 2016: It seems that the stall problem is handled better on modern x86s. See [INC instruction vs ADD 1: Does it matter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36510095/120163)

Comment: Setting SF/OF as well as ZF lets you `dec / jge` to loop from n down to 0, instead of n down to 1.  (i.e. fall through when `dec` produces `-1` instead of `0`.)  This is occasionally useful.

Comment: Update: Skylake is even better: it handles CF totally separately from the other FLAGS (SPAZO); the few instructions that need inputs from both read them as 2 separate inputs, so flag-merging isn't needed at all.  (But `cmova` and `cmovbe` are still 2 uops because of 4 total inputs, unlike other cmov instructions that only need 3.  jcc and setcc are always 1 uop even if they need 2 separate flag inputs). See @Bee's answer on [What is a Partial Flag Stall?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49868149)

Answer (score 6):

The question of why *sign* when you have *zero* flag set by inc/dec is best addressed with question: would you rather do without option ***a*** ?

```
a) for (n=7;n>=0;n--)   // translates to   `dec + jns`
b) for (n=8;n>0;n--)    // translates to   `dec + jnz`
```

As [Ira Baxter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13435633/1716339) already clarified, Carry flag is used in a lot of algorithms -- not only multiprecision arithmetic, but also for say bitmap processing in monochrome/cga/EGA era:
This shifts 80 pixel wide row one pixel right...

```
        mov cx, 10
begin:  lodsb
        rcr al,1   // this is rotate though carry:
        stosb      // for the algorithm to work, carry must not be destroyed
        LOOP begin //
```

But then: why parity?

I believe the answer is why not. This instruction set is from the late 70's, when transistors were scarce. Denying the calculation of parity flag for some particular instruction would have not made any sense, but just added to the complexity of the CPU.

Comment: "Why not parity"?  I'd be willing to bet that out of the milliions of INC/DEC instructions written by programmers that only a tiny number actually used the parity bit result.   Including (effectively) useless side effects in an instruction just means more documentation, more discussion like this, and more transistors in future implementation to be backwards compatible with stupid results.   Advice to architects:if a side effect is only rarely useful, don't do it.

Answer (score 2):

1. The instructions **inc** and **dec** are typically used to maintain iteration or loop count. Using 32 bits, the number of iterations can be as high as 4,294,967,295. This number is sufficiently large for most applications. What if we need a count that is greater than this? Do we have to use add instead of inc? This leads to the second, and the main, reason.
2. The condition detected by the carry flag can also be detected by the zero flag. Why? Because inc and dec change the number only by 1. For example, suppose that the ECX register has reached its maximum value 4,294,967,295 (FFFFFFFFH). If we then execute

   ```
                    inc ECX
   ```

   we would normally expect the carry flag to be set to 1. However, we can detect this condition by noting that ECX = 0, which sets the zero flag. Thus, setting the carry flag is really redundant for these instructions.

Comment: Yes for `inc`, but not for `dec`.  For `dec`, ZF==0 detects the iteration *before* carry (wraparound from 0 to 2^32-1).  I made the same comment this [on another answer that also made this argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13435142/why-do-the-inc-and-dec-instructions-not-affect-the-carry-flag-cf#comment86749885_13435722).

Answer (score -1):

Because there is no need to affect. It is quite enough to check the Zero flag.
So, after inc and dec instructions the carry flag remain the same and in some cases is this usefull.

Comment: That's true for `inc`: carry goes from 0xFFFF... to 0, so ZF and CF are equal.  But `dec` goes from `0` to `0xFFFF...`, so ZF is set on the decrement *before* carry.  The real reason I think is that `sub reg,1` is available if you need CF, and *normally* you don't need the CF result.  So preserving CF makes it possible to use it mixed with ADC, shifts, RCL, and other stuff that keeps something in CF.  (Of course this design decision was made for 8086, long before partial-register stalls were on the radar as a future problem.  At that point `loop` was efficient, so flagless looping was easy.)