# increment/decrement instructions' effects over the carry flag

Tags: assembly

My Question is regarding the assembly Language programming for a project i am going to deliver to Professor Aghazarian ...
There goes the Question:
Why is it that the Increment and/or the Decrement instructions have no change nor effect over the carry flag ?!

Comment: Already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13435142/why-the-inc-and-dec-instructions-do-not-affect-the-carry-flag

Comment: This is simply by design, and is useful when writing loops for carrying out arbitrary precision arithmetic.

Answer (score -1):

Think of it like this, you wish to add two binary values together:

```
1111
1111
```

This if you add these together it will trigger the carry flag, as adding two 1's together in a register will write a 0 at the registers position and will carry over a 1. Thus setting the carry flag to 1.

Inc/Dec instructions will just increment and decrement a value stored in a register.

Unless an overflow occurs from the incrementing, this will also set the carry flag.

Comment: Which - if I'm not mistaken - can also overflow and logically should also set the carry flag. So unless I'm mistaken that cannot be the complete answer, can it?

Comment: @DavidvanDriessche Yes i forgot about this you are correct.